# How to set the input impedance of an inverting amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance, inverting-amplifier, input-impedance

I want to Design an op-amp inverting amplifier circuit with
Closed-loop voltage gain = -10 and Input impedance = 10k

Since the it's an inverting amplifier then the Closed-loop voltage gain =-Rf/Rin
So if Rf = 100k and Rin = 10k then the Closed-loop voltage gain = -10

But I don't know how to set the input impedance of an inverting amplifier.

the input of this op-amp is 1 volt

Comment: What is the voltage at the inverting input of this op-amp?

Comment: the inverting input of this op-amp is 1 volt

Comment: Are you sure about that? Usually the non-inverting input is grounded.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany is it? What about op-amps in single supply applications? What if you want the amplifier to add a DC offset, as well as amplify?

Comment: In textbooks, it usually is (to being with). In your 'typical' schematic below, it definitely is. In reality, not always, of course. I just wanted him to think about it. I see no mention of Avo or GBW product, so it seems it's introductory level.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a typical op-amp inverting amplifier:

[image: schematic]

The input impedance is simply \$R_{in}\$, so for your requirements, \$R_{in} = 10k\Omega\$. \$R_f\$ is then whatever it needs to be to realize the desired gain. You want a gain of -10, so:

$$ -\frac{R_f}{10k\Omega} = -10 \\
R_f = 10 \cdot 10k\Omega = 100k\Omega $$

Why does the input impedance depend only on \$R_{in}\$? So long as the op-amp is not saturated, the inverting input is held at the same potential as the non-inverting input. Here, that's just ground, though any DC voltage works. So, you might as well consider \$R_{in}\$ as connected to ground, because the voltage is the same as it was. Once you realize the inverting input is effectively ground, it's easy to see the input impedance is just \$R_{in}\$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your circuit looks like the circuit here,

https://coefs.uncc.edu/dlsharer/files/2012/04/G9.pdf

the input impedance is simply Rin. You are all set. The first link has a very in-depth explanation. Here is a bit easier read:

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_2.html

The input impedance of any sort of amplifier is simply the impedance detected by the input signal. Thus, Zin = Vin/Iin. Since there is a virtual ground at the inverting input of the op-amp, the input impedance is equivalent to Rin. For example, if the input signal is 5V, Iin will be (5V-0)/10kΩ = 0.5mA. Then Rin = Vin/Iin = 5V/0.5mA = 10kΩ.

For a non-inverting amplifier, the input impedance would be the impedance from the non-inverting terminal to ground.